# Canonical for "can my boss restrict non-work related activity"

Tags: discussion

I saw the "[boss demands I don't talk to any people, because I can get coronavirus](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/154675/can-my-employer-legally-threaten-to-fire-me-unless-i-cut-off-in-person-contact-w)" question earlier today and recalled this similar question:

[Boss has banned cycling to work because he thinks it's unsafe](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/139577/boss-has-banned-cycling-to-work-because-he-thinks-its-unsafe)

I make this meta post to attract attention of the network since more similar questions can pop up. I have cast "VTC as dupe" the former question about virus.

Comment: Hm. I guess the answers would be really different if one of the similar questions do not take place in the US. Maybe this should be in the title?

Comment: Don't you feel that asking *“can my boss restrict non-work related activity”*, is the same as asking *“can my boss [legally] restrict non-work related activity”*? That I think would be asking for legal advice...

Comment: @DarkCygnus we are treading the line between Interpersonal Relations and legal here a lot.

Comment: Do we actually have and use any Canonicals for anything? I haven't noticed.